# Accessing Project Properties from settings.xml

Tags: maven, properties, settings

I'm trying to activate a profile in my settings.xml by the value of the pom's groupId.  To achieve that I have:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
      <profile>
    <id>imf</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>project.groupId</name>
        <value>myId</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
     . . .
    </properties>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
 </settings>
```

But this doesn't work.  Is it not possible to access project properties from settings?  The [reference material](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) says you can.

Just to verify my use of the property activator element, I conducted a sanity check using a property set from the command line.  Indeed, if I pass in -Dproject.groupId=myId to the mvn command line, my activation works.  This leads me to believe that the project properties simply aren't available in the settings.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your specific requirement cannot be achieved in the way you have tried.

`project.groupId` as a property name (or key) does not mean anything to maven.  maven understands (and expands) `${project.groupId}` and similar values in `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not actually the case here.  The property element of the profile activation takes the name of a property and a specified value of that property which serves as the condition upon which the profile is activated.

Comment: And, note, I included a sanity check in my question -- I passed the property in with the -D param; in that case it works fine.  This verifies my syntax, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @chad.  When passed with -D, the property was interpreted like any other - no specific semantic was associated with `project.groupId`.  You might as well have specified `<name>` as `myGroup` and it would have worked when run with `-DmyGroup=myId`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  The details of my sanity check aside, are you still suggesting that I need to use the ${} reference notation inside of the name element?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement - choosing between profiles depending on the groupId of the project (to choose between remote repositories). Then I noticed that my groupIds are always actually package names in my java class hierarchy. And package names are just simply directories in the filesystem. So my solution to this problem was to use the actication/file/exists tag:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>client1</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${basedir}/src/main/java/hu/client1</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>

            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>client2</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${basedir}/src/main/java/hu/client2</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>

            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>client3</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/client3</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>

           </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I'm more interested in why the project.properties doesn't work in this context.